# Importing 3D models/wireframes into QGIS

Tags: qgis, software-recommendations, 3d-model, qgis2threejs

I was wondering if Qgis2threejs is able to import 3D models (wireframes in 3D dxf) from GoCad, Datamine or any other 3D modelling software?

If not, is there any other plugins for QGIS that would be able to do this?